# VGA2HDMI monitor not recognized

Tags: drivers, display, display-resolution

I am a Linux newbie, and would appreciate any help with this.
I have an older computer with Intel GMA950 graphics in it and VGA port. My Samsung 4k monitor doesn't have any such port, so I have to use VGA2HDMI converter.
Maybe because of that, the Linux doesn't recognize the monitor and the best resolution it offers in the display menu is 1024x968, which is quite painful sight.
Is there any way to tell the Linux about the different monitor, or simply force it to use different resolution? I was using it in HD before I installed the Linux there, so the HW is capable of that...
I have checked everything through hwinfo, and the drivers for the VGA card seem to be correct.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Please provide your OS & release details; which is a starting point for providing help.  Also be specific, as Ubuntu LTS releases come with kernel stack choices which can make a large difference with this type of question, and if we know what you installed; we can know what you're current stack is.  (*drivers* is the end-user term for what are kernel modules; changing kernel stack causes different kernel modules (*drivers*) to be used...)

Comment: Hey there, thanks for trying to help! This is all new to me, but the below info is what I can see in the computer. Does that help?-Version-
Kernel  : Linux 5.15.0-56-generic (x86_64)
Version  : #62~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 22 21:24:20 UTC 2022
C Library  : GNU C Library / (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9.9) 2.31
Distribution  : Zorin OS 16.2

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Zorin forum.  (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Zorin so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux* found in the on-topic link)